# Immediate functions not running

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 3 immediate functions declared inside the handler function of an AWS Lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => { 
    (async doFirstStep => {
        console.log("First Step")
    })

    (async doSecondStep => {
        console.log("Second Step")
    })

    (async doThirdStep => {
        console.log("Third Step")
    })
}
```

When I run the test, the output is as follows:

```
// INFO First Step
```

If I change the order of the functions and put the doSecondStep before the doFirstStep then the output is:

```
// INFO Second Step
```

The problem is that only one function is executed, any hint on why the other functions are not working as they should be?

Comment: You're never calling the functions.

Comment: Add `()` to call the functioN: `(async doFirstStep => {...})()`

Comment: Actually, it's treating the second IIFE as the argument to the first one, that's why you're getting the first log message.

Comment: Please get out of the habit of omitting `;`, it causes confusing behavior like this.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much, I'll never omit the `;` again. I just dont get why the second is treated as argument to the first one, guess I have to do some more studying

Comment: Because it's after the function and inside parentheses. Putting it on a separate line doesn't change that.

Comment: It's like if you wrote `console.log <blank line> ("foo")`

Comment: @Barmar Got it, Thank you!!